# mysql selecting rows optimisation star or names

Tags: php, mysql

Say I have a table named `tablex`:

```
ID,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6.
```

Which of the following codes is FASTER, given that col4 is not needed in processing?

code 1 - `SELECT * FROM tablex`

code 2 - `SELECT ID,col1,col2,col3,col5,col6 FROM tablex`

(note col4 is missing in code 2, since its not needed, all col's are text of 80 varchars, ID is just int, auto-increment)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something you'll have to benchmark. For most small queries, you most likely won't notice any difference. If col4 was a BLOB that contains gigabyte-sized files, them most likely the specific column one (not the `*` format) would be faster, as that "useless" gigabyte wouldn't have to be fetched each time.

Comment: there should be a badge for this :D

Comment: @aletzo: I had this once too but it was upvoted recently so it's zero now :)

Answer (score 1):

Explicit listing of the attributes will be marginally (or not marginally) faster since `col4` won't need to be fetched and passed over the connection.

Also, if you are using query cache, the resultsets cached will be less in size and therefore more resultsets can be cached.

In general, you should always explicitly list your columns (not only for performance reasons, but for them too).

Answer (score -2):

code 2 is faster, but you should run some tests yourself to check it